# MSYS2 permissions

Tags: permissions, cygwin, chmod, msys

In Windows 10, with [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) I set my `fstab`  to:

```
none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,acl,user 0 0
```

I am unable to set execute permissions with `chmod`, despite having `acl` set in the `fstab`:

```
# echo > foo
# ls -l foo                              
-rw-r--r-- 1 ant None 1 Jun  1 19:18 foo 
# chmod +x foo
# ls -l foo                              
-rw-r--r-- 1 ant None 1 Jun  1 19:18 foo
```

In Cygwin, setting the same  `fstab`, for the same file I get:

```
# ls -l foo                                         
-rwxrwx---+ 1 ant None 1 Jun  1 19:18 foo
```

which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: `cygwin` has it's own `fstab`. What makes you think the output should be the same?

Comment: @DavidPostill:   I clarified that it is the same. Anyway, contrary to Cygwin, MSYS2 uses `noacl`  by default, that is why I originally stressed only the first `fstab`.

Comment: Cygwin knows how to map SIDs correctly (see [POSIX accounts, permission, and security](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html)). Does MSYS2 have the same functionality?

Comment: See this open ticket [#60 chmod being ignored](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/60/): "Status: open"

Comment: And this one [#158 issues with chmod and fstab](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/158/): "Status: wont-fix"

Comment: As an aside, shouldn't your command be `chmod +x foo`?

Comment: @DavidPostill: sorry just a typo: fixed `+x`

Comment: @DavidPostill: I actually  read the wont-fix thread on SF  before posting here. It seems that the actual problem there is not with permissions, but with wrong libraries. In the same thread a MSYS2 developer [says](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/158/#6e56) "`chmod` works for me when I re-mount without noacl.". He restates the same [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/60/#1d42). As an extra test, I tried also totally removing the `acl` option, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've wasted quite a bit of time on this, so let me capture my findings:

Changing fstab helps but you must chmod the file via a path that goes through the mount point. In other words:

```
mkdir /c/test # Outside MSYS2 root (/).
cd /c/test
touch foo
chmod +x foo # works but presumably won't if inside MSYS root.
chmod +x /c/test/foo # works and presumably will if inside MSYS root.
chmod +x c:\test\foo # does not work -- go figure.
```

Pretty brain-dead, if you ask my humble opinion. And the solution seems pretty simple: change from noacl to acl on all default MSYS2 mounts (the MSYS2 root mount is created automatically and there is no way to change to acl from fstab -- correction: supposedly possible with the override mount option).

Comment: `c:\test\foo # does not work` is probably because MSYS2 `bash` interprets the backslash as escape character, and so `\t` becomes a TAB character.